# How can I get $_GET values to a variable

Tags: php, get-method

In my page, there are multiple $_GET values. ie

```
if(isset($_GET["projects"]))
{ .....    }
else if(isset($_GET["research"]))
{ ...... }
else if(isset($_GET["publication"]))
{ ..... }
```

...upto 10 elseif's

Can I shorten this?
Can I get these values {projects,research, publication,..} in a variable.?

Comment: They are already in a variable, you can just use them as is. If you want to set another variable with those values, you can simply assign normally `$projects = $_GET['projects']`... not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Hard to provide an answer without more details about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why not use one variable with "what to do" as the value? The primary cause comes because of the *disjoint operations* (as recognized by `else if`) based on the first of the set of variables which is present..

Comment: And why are you using `else if` rather than one variable with a value you can check?

Comment: I need a code like $type=$_GET.

Comment: You are having trouble to do something as simple as assign the value of a variable to another?

Comment: if i use, as you say, it will be like this .. : `if($_GET["abc"]) type="abc"; else if($_GET["sss"]) $type="sss"; ....etc.

Comment: Provide more details about what input you expect. Will there only be a single value in `$_GET` with changing key name? Or will there be many values in `$_GET` but one of them will be `projects` or `research` etc.?

Comment: @NisfanSabith are you trying to check if all values in a form have been filled out??

Comment: The real question is this - is there more data being submitted other than just type=projects or are there sub parts to each one.. like projects being the type, but a secondary line being type_of_project = media... etc...

Comment: actually, am trying to read some values using a textarea with respect to the $_GET value. is, if $_GET='publication' insert the textarea content to db with type='publication'. If the $_GET['project'] then type attribute (of db) has a value of 'project'. I have about 12 values for the type attribute, and now am using an else_if ladder.

Comment: okay - first, I would use a switch statement instead of an else_if ladder in general... if the value of type is set at all in advance and not intuitively based on content. It tends to result in cleaner easier to follow code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I guess I figured out what you want from your comments. Lets see.

```
$types = array('projects', 'research', 'publication'); // add as many as you want
$valid = array_intersect_key($_GET, array_flip($types));

if (count($valid) > 1)
    die "More than one category is set, this is invalid.";

if (!$valid)
    die "No category was set, you must choose one.";

foreach ($valid as $type => $value) // just to split this one element array key/value into distinct variables
{
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value); // assuming you are using mysql_*
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE $type = '$value'";
}

...
```

Comment: that does it. Thank You @Havenard :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$projects = $_GET["projects"];
```

Or just use directly from `$_GET`, this is an associative array with all the values.

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value){
    if(!empty($value)){
        $type = $key; //if you expect a single item
        $type[] = $key; //if you expect multiple items
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean, I can use $type=$_GET;

Comment: If you use $type = $_GET; then you have an array of all your values. But it's just like $_GET. So $type['projects'] equals $_GET['projects']

Comment: I need these get values {projects, publications, ...etc} to $type. So I can use the $type in query. Otherwise I need a elseif ladder. :(

Comment: Added a foreach loop to get all the not empty variables in $type.
It could be that you may need to use '' != $value in the if statement

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can assign these in a variable -

```
if(isset($_GET["projects"]))
{
    $value = $_GET['projects'];
}
else if(isset($_GET["research"]))
{
    $value = $_GET['research'];
}
else if(isset($_GET["publication"]))
{
    $value = $_GET['publication'];
}
echo $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're expecting a single value in `$_GET`, like `?projects=foo` or `?research=bar`. In that case:

```
$type  = key($_GET);
$value = $_GET[$type];

echo "$type = $value";
```

Answer (score 0):

if the intent is to check if values on a form have been answered/filled out you could use

```
if(isset($_GET['project'] || ... || isset($_GET['publication'])
{
 // Insert Code Here
}
else
{
 // Insert Code Here
}
```

The above code is assuming the fields are not text fields or textareas if those are the types of inputs then instead of

```
if(isset($_GET['project']))
```

use

```
if($_GET['project'] != "")
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely understood what you are saying but looks like that you are trying to execute something when all `$_GET` is true. If so then use the code below

```
if(isset($_GET["projects"]) && isset($_GET["research"]) && isset($_GET["publication"]) )
{ .....    }
```

Hope this helps you